# Notepad++: Remove lines containing the word "Correct" and the two lines above it

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, text-files

I have a text-file like this:

```
010 2015.06.29 09:57:57.731 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used postadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
010 2015.06.29 09:57:58.220 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No tussenpersoon found with the given strings: DIFFERENT_TEXTS
010 2015.06.29 09:57:59.288 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] More than one cluster (2) found with the given string: DIFFERENT_TEXTS
010 2015.06.29 09:58:00.192 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] More than one cluster (2) found with the given string: DIFFERENT_TEXTS
010 2015.06.29 09:58:02.766 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used bezoekadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
Trying to retrieve notaris with postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:02.778 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] Correct notaris is found when using the postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:03.647 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used bezoekadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
Trying to retrieve notaris with postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:03.659 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] Correct notaris is found when using the postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:03.991 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used bezoekadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
Trying to retrieve notaris with postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:04.004 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used postadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
```

What I'd like to achieve is removing all of the following lines (containing the word "Correct"):

```
Correct notaris is found when using the postadres instead of bezoekadres
```

Including the two lines above it. So in the example above, I want to remove the following lines:

```
010 2015.06.29 09:58:02.766 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used bezoekadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
Trying to retrieve notaris with postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:02.778 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] Correct notaris is found when using the postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:03.647 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] No notaris found with the given strings (used bezoekadres): DIFFERENT_TEXTS
Trying to retrieve notaris with postadres instead of bezoekadres
010 2015.06.29 09:58:03.659 WARN  ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT] Correct notaris is found when using the postadres instead of bezoekadres
```

- NOTE: `ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT` and `DIFFERENT_TEXTS` are replaced for
  confidentially. As stated by the names, the `ALWAYS_SAME_TEXT` is
  always the same piece of text, and the `DIFFERENT_TEXTS` have
  different texts per log-line.

I know I can use `Ctrl + F` -> `Mark-tab` -> `Bookmark line checkbox` -> `Mark all` with the Search-term `Correct`, but how can I also mark all the two lines above the lines containing the word `"Correct"`, if this is even possible in Notepad++. There are too many of them to mark by hand.

---

Actually, I'm asking the wrong question, so let me try again:

I have a `.txt` file with log-lines like in the example above and want to remove all lines containing the word `Correct` and every two lines above that line. I prefer to do this in Notepad++, but if someone has an easy copy-paste file I can run in `Visual Studio` to achieve the same goal it's also fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*\bCorrect\b.*[\r\n]*
```

Replacement string:

```
empty string
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I edited some small mistakes (typos), but it works like a charm.

Comment: ya, in java we need to use double backslash.